# Are questions about PS4 themes on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask about finding a PS4 theme that uses the main [Playstation 4 theme music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uFWnIGmiMQ), as it's just about the most calming thing I've listened to.

It feels like it would be either a needle in a haystack situation, or a recommendation question, so I'm double checking here first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions about how to change themes, how to load 3rd party themes (if that's even possible), or basic questions about how to get a theme from the store would all most likely be on-topic.

Your question, which very much looks to be a shopping recommendation, would probably be off-topic.

Comment: You can set custom background images as your PS4's theme, but setting custom music is not supported

Comment: @Wondercricket Definitely one of the saddest oversights, not seeing custom music. MBraedley, thanks, I figured it would read as shopping. Thanks!